# Mysql big table vs joins

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have one (items [id, name, color, size, etc] ) table with more than 6000. And i think it can reach 10000 at most.
In that table basically is information about, well, items. I also have 5 constant storehouses' tables  and from 0 to 7 temporary storehouses' tables.
Those tables are like this (id, item_id, quantity). I tried to normalize that database by combining those storehouses in one table (id, item_id, quantity, storehouse_id). That made searches extremely slow 6-10sec when searching for multiple items from all storehouses using self-joins. Then I decided to combine items with that newly created database (id, name, color, size, etc, storehouse1_quantity, storehouse2_quantity, etc). That made queries less than a 0.1s for any request. But now the database is very denormalized. As storehouses have no more than 2000 items and mostly less than 500.
I can live with that if there is no better way. I don't know where to look at to make database more logic and easier to maintain.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the normalize approach is the "right" way, and since DB engines are built to deal with this, I'd start looking at what your index arrangement is.  If there a lot of lookups/joins, there generally should be an index so that MySQL doesn't have to chug through all the text.

Comment: Every field in table is indexed by which the search can be made. It just that search makes same loop through the table as many times as there are storehouses and joining that to the items table again many times

Comment: I can only suggest to look at how you're storing this data...if it's that difficult to get, perhaps a design adjustment for some summary information somewhere might be in order.